# How can I set the value of a parameter inside of an object?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this list that I am checking and then creating another list, where the definition is not equal to null.

```
 var new = rootObject.webWordForms
            .Where(w => w.definition != null)
            .ToList();

public class WebWordForm
{
    public string definition { get; set; }
    public string partOfSpeech { get; set; }
    public int sourceId { get; set; }
    public List<string> synonyms { get; set; }
    public List<string> typeOf { get; set; }
    public List<string> hasTypes { get; set; }
    public List<string> derivation { get; set; }
    public List<string> examples { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a simple way that I could also set the `sourceId` in my `rootObject.webWordForms` list to the value of 2?

Comment: You should refrain from modifying the objects being queried when using LINQ. Do a loop afterwards and modify the objects.

Comment: Check for `.ForEach()` and run it on `new`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Not sure if it makes a difference but this is the last thing I do with the object. In fact "var new =" is actually "return" but I just put it the way I did as I wanted to make the question simple. Thanks

Comment: Note: you can also do something like `.Where(w => w.definition != null && (w.partOfSpeech = "Noun") != null).ToList()`, which will work because of lazy evaluation and because `ToList()` enumerates the list. Just be sure to add a `// yuck` at the end of the line. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var new = rootObject.webWordForms
            .Where(w => w.definition != null)
            .Select(w => new WebWordForm{
  definition = w.definition,
  partOfSpeech = w.partOfSpeech,
  sourceId = 2,
  synonyms= w.synonyms,
  typeOf = w.typeOf,
  hasTypes = w.hasTypes,
  derivation = w.derivation,
  examples = w.examples
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Also, optionally simplify this by omitting the `definition = ` etc.: `new WebWordForm { w.definition, w.partOfSpeech, sourceId = 2, w.synonyms ...`

Answer (score 3):

You could use List `ForEach` method to do this, but please mind this is nothing different than looping.

```
var list = rootObject.webWordForms
            .Where(w => w.definition != null)
            .ToList();

list.ForEach(x=> x.sourceId =2);
```

Comment: That's not especially useful, as you're basically creating a new List, running the loop on it and then throw the list away - in order to return it, you'd have to re-create it (or store it before calling `ForEach`): `var stuff = rootObject.Where(...).ToList(); stuff.ForEach(...); return stuff;` This is because `ForEach` returns `void`.

Comment: @HenrikIlgen, I got what you mean. Updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @HariPrasad - is it possible to combine those two LINQ statements into one by just adding .ForEach before or after the .ToList() ?

Comment: @Alan The problem in combining those two statements is `ForEach` is void method, so it will not return modified list to you, so you have to separate this execution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.ForEach()` on `new`, this would iterate on list `new` and update the param.

```
var finalList = rootObject.webWordForms
          .Where(w => w.definition != null)
          .ToList();

finalList.ForEach(n=>n.sourceId = 2);
```

*Note* - If the queried final list is your `return` you need to do above operations before returning anything.

While I am suggesting `ForEach()`, many articles focus on avoiding it.

An alternative,

```
var finalList = rootObject.webWordForms
                .Where(w => w.definition != null)
                .ToList();

finalList.All(n=>{
                 n.sourceId = 2;
                 return true;
             });
```

Comment: Yeah but let's not use the keyword `new` as a variable name :-)

Comment: @ShaunakD - is it possible to combine those two statements by just adding the .All after the .ToList() ?

Comment: No, not possible. `All` returns bool. In any case except the above answer you'd need 2 statements.